# Using dom-if for conditionals in arrays

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In 0.5 I could use the expressions in the dom-if to select for certain things in arrays while looping through them. How could I achieve the same effect in 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more efficient to use the `filter/observe` feature of `dom-repeat` instead of nesting `dom-if`. `filter` specifies a method that identifies records to display from your collection, `observe` tells the `dom-repeat` what data to observe to know when to re-run the filter. E.g.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{records}}" filter="hasPersonLabel" observe="item.labels">
...
hasPersonLabel: function (labels) {
    return (labels.indexOf("Person") >= 0);
}
```

Documentation is here (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#filtering-and-sorting-lists).

Answer (score 1):

You use a function like

```
hasPersonLabel: function (labels) {
    if (labels.indexOf("Person") === -1) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

And then you can use

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{records}}">
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{isPerson(item.labels)}}">
```